# Deleted some files from home folder

Tags: home-directory, delete, restore

I have recently installed Ubuntu for the first time in my life. So I am fairly new to it.

I have deleted some files from my home folder. But now the problems have started. The system volume automatically reduces to zero. Further, as soon as I restarted my system, my panel settings we restored to default.
When I right click in my home folder, it gives an option of 'restore missing files' but I am not able to restore them.

Please guide me how to restore them.

Thanks
Narendra

Comment: how old is your installation? is your .config folder still there or was that deleted? I would pick the option of a fresh installation in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Your home folder contains literally every file and setting which you, as a standard user, are able to edit, and which your programs (including the Unity desktop environment and/or panels) are able to edit and save their configurations in. It's basically a sealed box, which you and your programs can only get out of if you know your password (which is one of the reasons Ubuntu is so secure - a virus would need it too). This means it contains all settings related to your desktop, and it explains why your panel settings restore to default if you delete it.

In general, don't touch (or delete!) any hidden files in that folder (files starting with a full stop - or period if you're American). Pressing CTRL+h toggles visibility of hidden files.

As for restoring them... if you moved them to the wastebasket, they are easily restored by opening the wastebasket, selecting the files you deleted, and clicking the "Restore Selected Items" button. It will probably ask you if you wish to overwrite the newly created files which replaced them, you do.

If you permanently deleted them, then you permanently deleted them. It would be easier just to change the settings back yourself than to try to recover them.

---

Also, can you please clarify what you meant by system volume reducing to zero?

Also, the "Restore missing files" option you mentioned only restores from a backup. If you did not make one, you cannot restore it.

Comment: @captain_G @ Sman: My .config folder is still there and computer is working fine. Thanx for reply :)

Comment: But I am not able to log in into localhost:8000. Would that be because of this reason? If yes, is there any solution?