# remove .dat files from /home/user/

Tags: filesystem

I'm new to Ubuntu after jumping the OS X ship since Captain Tim is starting to lose it. So I've been trying it on dualboot, and I love it.

But I see some files in my Home folder which I -think- I can delete, but I also know it could [implode everything](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185943/deleted-some-files-from-home-folder).
Can anyone tell me if these files are safe to delete?

- dht.dat
- dht_feed.dat
- Examples
- Release.key
- resume.dat
- rss.dat
- settings.dat

[image]

Edit: Well, I moved all files to the trash and since then I experienced several freezes, crashes etc. Which would all be fixed by a (forced) reboot, but they kept happening, so I moved all items back from the trash and so far so good; no more freezes (yet).

So appearantly there is something with these files. How could I debug any errors?

Comment: Why not put them together in a folder somewhere? If your system implodes, you can always move them back. If not, delete the folder after a while.

Comment: and where did they come from? Looks like you unpacked something in your home? "Examples" should be a default directory.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if it's in your home directory and doesn't start with a dot (`.`) you can delete without affecting the per-user configuration. You obviously loose all the data in those files and directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me if these files are safe to delete?

- That is for you to decide.
- They don't belong in /home/$USER/ though.
- It looks like you open an install file in /home/$USER/.
- Should be safe to remove in my opinion but you never know ;)

Even so ... from command line you can delete this with ...

```
rm dht.dat dht_feed.dat Release.key resume.dat rss.dat settings.dat
```

And if you want to make a backup first ...

```
mkdir ~/backup
mv dht.dat dht_feed.dat Release.key resume.dat rss.dat settings.dat ~/backup/
```

I left "Examples" out of it even though it is harmless to delete; it is a default directory and not part of the other files your listed.